# Does Python implicitly return None in modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, module, bytecode

I was playing around with Python bytecode with the [**`dis`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#module-dis) module when I noticed something about bytecode generated for modules. Given a small test module named `mod.py`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello World")
```

I created a code object for it with the [**`compile()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) function:

```
>>> cobj = compile(open("mod.py").read(), "mod", "exec")
```

and then, disassembled the code object to view the bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis(cobj)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__name__)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 ('__main__')
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       22

  2          12 LOAD_NAME                1 (print)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello World')
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             21 POP_TOP
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

What struck me were the two last commands [**`LOAD_CONST`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_CONST) and [**`RETURN_VALUE`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-RETURN_VALUE) which, if my understanding is correct, place the constant `None` on the *value stack* and consequently return it.

Do modules implicitly return `None` and, if so, why?

Comment: This is about the code object, not the fact that it is a module.  The bytecode needs to return something so that  `exec(cobj)` has a return value.

Comment: Modules don't return anything because they don't return. They can be imported, executed directly, or compiled, but that's about all.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen The module is represented by a code object. Final returns inside code objects (for functions, classes or modules) are simply a means to represent termination of the current frame of execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in a nutshell, modules do implicitly return `None` in order for the big evaluation loop inside **[`ceval.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L1925)** to be able detect when to the current frame is finished and terminate.

Interestingly, you can see this even when a python file that is completely empty is interpreted, from a terminal:

```
jim@lpt> touch file.py
jim@lpt> python -m dis file.py
1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            3 RETURN_VALUE
```

This behavior is not limited to modules but, rather, *[for anything that can form a code block](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#structure-of-a-program)*; this includes **class definitions**:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> co = compile("class mycls: pass", filename = "stdin", mode = "exec")
>>> dis(co.co_consts[0])  # co_consts[0] contains class definition
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__name__)
              3 STORE_NAME               1 (__module__)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 ('mycls')
              9 STORE_NAME               2 (__qualname__)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

and **function bodies**:

```
>>> def foo(): pass

>>> dis(foo)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

That is, the `RETURN_VALUE` bytecode command *[terminates the current block that was executing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L3643)* and returns (`LOAD_CONST`) the value on the top of the stack to the callee (if there exists one).

The only caveat is that it is that specifying a custom return value is only allowed for functions, in class definitions and modules a return value doesn't have much of a purpose and as such trying to specify one results in an appropriate `SyntaxError`.

---

For the people interested in the source code for this, you can find it by stepping through the functions defined in **[`compile.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/compile.c)**, from the documentation in `compile.c`:

```
 * The primary entry point is PyAST_Compile(), which returns a
 * PyCodeObject.  The compiler makes several passes to build the code
 * object:
 *   1. Checks for future statements.  See future.c
 *   2. Builds a symbol table.  See symtable.c.
 *   3. Generate code for basic blocks.  See compiler_mod() in this file.
 *   4. Assemble the basic blocks into final code.  See assemble() in
 *      this file.
 *   5. Optimize the byte code (peephole optimizations).  See peephole.c
```

The relevant steps are `3.` and `4.` or **[`compiler_mod`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/compile.c#L1384)** and **[`assemble`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/compile.c#L4939)** functions